# C++ mySQL connector multiple errors (Windows)

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, unresolved-external

I've been trying to get MySQL working with Visual Studio 2012 and Windows (x86) in general. I don't have problems on Linux, however, I get a lot errors on Windows. This is my code (I've copied from some site to test if it really won't work)

```
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

const string server   = "tcp://somemysqlserver.com";
const string username = "someusers";
const string password = "somepass";

int main()
{
    sql::Driver     *driver;
    sql::Connection *dbConn; 
    sql::Statement  *stmt;  
    sql::ResultSet  *res; 

    try
    {
        driver = get_driver_instance();
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not get a database driver. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }


    try
    {
        dbConn = driver->connect(server, username, password);
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "Could not connect to database. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }

    stmt = dbConn->createStatement(); 

    try
    {
        stmt->execute("USE mysql");   

        res = stmt->executeQuery("show tables"); 
    }
    catch (sql::SQLException e)
    {
        cout << "SQL error. Error message: " << e.what() << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(1);
    }


    while (res->next())
    {
        cout << res->getString(1) << endl;                
    }

    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete dbConn;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem was first some error in config.h (line 60, seems like a popular error).I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065606/int8-t-redefinition-error-in-config-h-when-trying-to-connect-mysql-cpp-conne), didn't work but the problem fixed itself somehow. Now I get the following errors:

> ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall
>   sql::SQLString::~SQLString(void)" (__imp_??1SQLString@sql@@QAE@XZ)
>   referenced in function __catch$_main$0 1>
>
> ConsoleApplication1.obj :
>   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &)"
>   (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   referenced in function __catch$_main$0 1>
>   ConsoleApplication1.obj :
>
> error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport)
>   public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)"
>   (__imp_??0SQLString@sql@@QAE@QBD@Z) referenced in function
>   __catch$_main$2 1>
>
> ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol >"__declspec(dllimport) public: class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const & __thiscall
>   sql::SQLString::asStdString(void)const "
>   (__imp_?asStdString@SQLString@sql@@QBEABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
>   referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream > & __cdecl std::operator<<(class
>   std::basic_ostream > &,class
>   sql::SQLString const &)"
>   (??6std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@ABVSQLString@sql@@@Z)
>   1>
>
> ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__get_driver_instance referenced in function _main 1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall
>   sql::SQLException::~SQLException(void)"
>   (__imp_??1SQLException@sql@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function
>   __catch$_main$0

I really don't know how to fix this, I've tried almost everything as changing the libs or reading stuff, documentations and such things, nothing helped. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: see what will happen when you remove all stuff from catch{} blocks

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain, that's not the problem. I've pretty much tried everything as optimizing the code, reading tutorials and stuff - nothing helped. I tried linking libraries as said in the tutorials and I yet again get these errors such as ````Error 8 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sql::SQLString::SQLString(char const * const)" ````

Comment: That's a linker error, you should provide your linker arguments so that we can specify why it isn't linked.