# How to set macros in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to use the fix from ['int8_t' : redefinition error in config.h when trying to connect mysql cpp connector to visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065606/int8-t-redefinition-error-in-config-h-when-trying-to-connect-mysql-cpp-conne) which suggests setting a macro

`HAVE_INT8_T=1`

I know how to use the Preprocessor to define variables, but in that case, I would have expected the answer to be in the form

`#define HAVE_INT8_T 1`

Is this an equivalent suggestion? Or do I need to set the macro in a project settings menu somewhere?

If so, I've read the [documentation for Property Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/675f1588.aspx), but I can't locate the Macros menu. A screenshot would be helpful, if this is the way I need to go.

Comment: The documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hhzbb5c8.aspx), but there's also a page with a list of them for your project in the properties, which is also explained in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope is different if you declare it into the property pages for the entire Project or into just one file:

[image]

If you need that into one file only (or if you're comfortable with a header for that), go for it. Otherwise do it at project scope.